# Vuforia & Unity: Build UWP Successfully but No Live Camera Feed (Black Screen)

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

Unity Version: Unity 2019.3.9f1

Vuforia Version: 9.0.12

The app works fine in unity editor, it builds and runs successfully without error but no camera feed (black screen). Can't seem to find up to date solutions online.

1. Updated the Vuforia version to 9.2.7 does not seem to solve the problem.
2. I don't think to check the "Vuforia Augmented Reality Supported" under the "XR Settings" is an option, because it's able to deprecate. Also Checking the "Windows Mixed Reality" plug-in under XR Plug-in Management didn't solve the problem.
3. I already checked the "InternetClient" and "WebCam" in the publish setting for UWP.
4. Do I need to change anything in ARCamera's "Open Vuforia Engine configuration"? Some solutions mention disabling the Vuforia play mode will help, but I can't seem to find the option anywhere.

Anyone encountered the same issue and find a solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a current solution, but would like to share my experience working with vuforia, UWP.

I found that there are varying breaking versions of unity and vuforia's SDK.
The latest version may not necessarily work I had to trial and error before I found a compatible version, so you might want to try that out. perhaps a older version of either unity/vuforia in reference with https://library.vuforia.com/platform-support/supported-versions.html

And yeah, definitely run your "hello world" tests on the sample projects first.
Best of luck, it's a great SDK ,once you get it to work.

Comment: Thanks for your info although it's not what I was looking for. I figured it out, not all computers are supported [link](https://library.vuforia.com/content/vuforia-library/en/platform-support/vuforia-engine-recommended-devices.html). I tried it on my phone and it did work.